# Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment error in hp UFT

Tags: vbscript, qtp

```
Set ParentObject=Browser("Title:=Sign-In").Page("Title:=Sign-In Home Page")
PropertyRequired="name"
PropertyValue="Agree and Login"
Result="yes"


Function WebButton(ParentObject,PropertyRequired,PropertyValue,Result)
Call ReportResult(Result)
Dim hit
hit=0
   If PropertyRequired="" then
       PropertyRequired="name"
   End If

 If ParentObject.WebButton(PropertyRequired &":="&PropertyValue).exist then 
     ParentObject.WebButton(PropertyRequired &":="&PropertyValue).click
     hit=1
 End if

If hit>0 then
    Reporter.reportevent micpass,"The button: "&PropertyValue,"Clicked    sucessfully"
else
    Reporter.reportevent micpass,"The button: "&PropertyValue,"not Clicked sucessfully"
End if
End Function
```

After I Call this function, then an error " Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignments" displayed.

```
Call WebButton(ParentObject,PropertyRequired,PropertyValue,Result)
```

Comment: Did it give any line number? can you give the complete code?

Answer (score 0):

I just executed your piece of code .I dont find any issues .

Answer (score 0):

Try using parenthesis when calling Reporter.reportevent so it's like this:

```
Reporter.reportevent (micpass, "The button: " & PropertyValue, "Clicked sucessfully")
```